# saving dynamically added content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically added multiple elements using jquery. Now i want to save that page, so that if i reload that page everything should be there. How should i do that?

HTML code

```
<body>
   <button id="add_div" >Add Div</button> 
   <button id="add_button">Add Button</button>
</body>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add div function
    $("#add_div").click(function () {
  var p= $("body").append(
  '<div class="module_holder">Hello there</div>');
  $(".module_holder").draggable().resizable().css( "background-color","red");

});

  // Add Button function
      $('#add_button').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');
        $("body").append(r);
    });

});
```

Comment: use cookie or html5 localstorage

Comment: @Cattla can u plz provide me link. i searched it on google but couldn't find any good tutorial.

Comment: Do you want the actual html to be saved, or for the page to be cached for the user?

Comment: @dwreck08 actually i want to know both. thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1

you have to use localstorage, if your website can be accessed from number of browsers than you can use common [jaydata](http://jaydata.org/) library to work with local storage

## Solution 2

You have to save your data on any server using server side technology like ASP.NET or PHP or JSP and you can retrieve your information on page load using AJAX. If there is any content stored on server side than you have to load with page, if there is nothing it means that you have to just load only two buttons.